# direct sum of injective hull of two modules is equal to the injective hull of direct sum of those modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum, injective-module

why is the direct sum of injective hull of two modules equal to the injective hull of direct sum of those modules? In other words, $E(M\oplus N)=E(M)\oplus E(N)$

Comment: Are you assuming the underlying ring to be commutative?

Comment: yes, but i don't know if it's also true if the ring isnoncommutative?

Comment: It is true for any ring, commutative or not.

Comment: Also, referring to it as "the" injective hull is a little imprecise. It is unique up to isomorphism, but not a unique isomorphism. It's kind of like algebraic closure of a field in that sense: there are in general many automorphisms of $E(M)$ that act as the identity on $M$, and $E(M)$ is not functorial in $M$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix the definitions: if $A \subseteq B$ are modules, then $B$ is an *essential extension* of $A$ if whenever $C$ is a submodule of $B$ with $C \cap A=0$, we have $C=0$. An *injective hull* of a module $M$ is an injective module $E(M)$ together with an inclusion $M \hookrightarrow E(M)$ making $E(M)$ an essential extension of $M$.

Since $I$ is injective iff $\mathrm{Hom}(\cdot,I)$ is exact, finite sums of injective modules are injective. Thus $E(M) \oplus E(N)$ is injective. The inclusions $M \hookrightarrow E(M)$ and $N \hookrightarrow E(N)$ induce an inclusion $M \oplus N \hookrightarrow E(M) \oplus E(N)$. It remains to show that this is an essential extension of $M \oplus N$.

Here are the key points: since $E(M)$ is an essential extension of $M$, we obtain that $E(M) \oplus N$ is an essential extension of $M \oplus N$. Since $E(N)$ is an essential extension of $N$, we obtain that $E(M) \oplus E(N)$ is an essential extension of $E(M) \oplus N$. Now use the fact that if $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ with $B$ an essential extension of $A$ and $C$ an essential extension of $B$ then $C$ is an essential extension of $A$.

Comment: but the sum of injective modules need not to be injective.

Comment: it is true just when R is noetherian

Comment: @user297564  Finite sums of injectives are injective. I gave the proof!

Comment: oh yes, i'm so sorry

Comment: No worries! Hope it was helpful!